# Visual Studio code: SSH remote doesn‘t quit all commands started by visual studio code

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, visual-studio-code

I'm using the remote-ssh extension by Microsoft to edit code on a Linux server of my work group.

I've noticed a lot of "bash", "sleep" and some "node" commands running on the server with my user and it looks like, visual studio code started this commands and didn't quit them with me quitting visual studio code or closing the remote connection.

Anyone with the same problem and/or a solution?

Comment: Try this. Settings -> Features -> Terminal -> `Integrated: Confirm on exit` : Enable the option. This will ensure VSCode informs you about the active terminals while exiting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it doesn‘t solve my problem. If i enable this option and close the remote connection, I get this message:
"There is an active terminal session, do you want to kill it?"
But if I press "yes", there are still new "bash", "sleep" and "node" commands running.